# Global settings for custom firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I want to send custom crash log (like userid, name, etc) on every crash so we can trace back which user experience crash.

My question is that how can I set custom crash report at a single place and automatically send on every crash?

Comment: Have a look [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489)

Comment: @Lin, Please refer my below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add custom keys** in `firebase crashlytics`

Custom keys help you get the specific state of your app leading up to a crash. You can associate arbitrary key/value pairs with your crash reports, and see them in the Firebase console.

> There are five methods to set keys. Each handles a different data type:

```
Crashlytics.setString(key, value);

Crashlytics.setBool(String key, boolean value);

Crashlytics.setDouble(String key, double value);

Crashlytics.setFloat(String key, float value);

Crashlytics.setInt(String key, int value);
```

In your case you can add for Eg. Like below

```
// for userid
Crashlytics.setString("userid", userIdValue);

// for name
Crashlytics.setString("name", nameValue);
```

For more refrence see this [Add Custom Logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#add_custom_logs)

> **Imp Note:-** Crashlytics supports a maximum of 64 key/value pairs. Once you reach this threshold, additional values are not saved. Each key/value pair can be up to 1 kB in size.